# Different texture generation methods with opengl

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm experimenting with texture generation so I can begin to implement height map generation/terrain generation. Right now I'm just experimenting with different generating functions. Right now I'm just generating a 256x256 rgb texture when I apply the sin function to the sum of the normalized coordinates I get the following:

[image: <x,y>/|<x.y>|]

When I apply sin to the sum of the unnormalized coordinates I get the following:

[image: <x,y>]

Is there a way I can hit the whole of the sin domain multiple times while keeping the normalized coordinates so that there is the wave-like texture of the unnormalized version but it retains the smoothness from the normalized coordinates

Comment: Did you consider multiplying your sum by some number between 0 and 1 to reduce the frequency of the waves?

Comment: Yes, this was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately it didn't give me the effect I was looking for, it gave me more of the same as the normalized coordinates. @DMGregory

Comment: Did you try a bigger number?

Comment: I tried a whole range of numbers between from 0..1, things bigger than 1 just made the texture white